# Why Does VS2010 "Lose" my reference on build?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-services, console-application

I've developed a class library that does stuff, and tested it with unit tests. The library and tests build and work fine. I then added in a Windows Service project to the solution to wrap the library up in.

I've added a reference to my class project, added a using statement and var'd an object from the class lib. It colour-codes just fine and Refactor can ctrl-click and navigate into it, but when I build the project/solution, it claims the type of my is unknown and there's an exception:

> The type or namespace name
>   'EmailLoaderCore' does not exist in
>   the namespace 'MPN.Apollo' (are you
>   missing an assembly reference?)

This doesn't make sense to me. I've tried removing the reference, cleaning the solution, re-creating the reference, but no joy. Am I doing something wrong or is VS2010 being weird?

Comment: Did you add a project reference or an assembly reference?

Comment: Do you get the error at compile time?  Or at run time?

Comment: That's the third one in the past two days.  Did they slip in a Windows Update?

Comment: Project reference and it's a compile-time issue. I.E load vs2010/solution and it looks good, then build and it blows up.

Comment: Thank you for your patronising and irrelevant comment Anuradha.

Comment: @AnuradhaJayasena I always find it interesting when I have a problem, I google it, find a question identical to my problem, find an answer that fixes my problem, then find a comment like yours.

Comment: Actually, AnuradhaJayasena in a way gave the solution. :P

Answer (score 53):

Turns out, if you show the Warnings in the Build window, it tells you why :) Doh.

Service projects default to "Framework 4 Client Profile" now, and that is a sub-set of Framework 4 which means no linking to anything else other than that. Changed the project type to Framework 4 and all is good.

Answer (score 4):

When there is a difference in Target .Net Framework(under project settings), it will create reference missing problems. It creates strange problems like when i add the reference it gets added. But when i build, again it will loose the reference. After making Target frame work same for both the project resolved the error.