# Visual Studio loses reference when attempting to build

Tags: c#, thrift

I started using Thrift about a week ago. I got the latest source from SVN and built the C# library (Thrift.dll). I used the library to prototype a TCP client/server with  the data types that my team will be using. This worked with no problem, I just followed the example code in the SVN repo.

Yesterday, I wanted to run the same test but over HTTP instead. I searched around online some and found out that from the time I got the code last week until yesterday patch "THRIFT-322" https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-322

Was applied to the trunk. So I updated my thrift source from SVN and saw the new THttpHandler class. I rebuilt the Thrift.dll so I can use the THttpHandler class but now whenever I reference the new dll Visual Studio 2010 gives me an error at compile time: "The type or namespace "Thrift" could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)". When I replace the reference with the old Thrift.dll that I have I do not get this error.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, I just recompiled the Thrift.dll from the SVN source and I can no longer link to the Thrift.dll. When I first add the reference it seems like it's going to work fine. Visual Studio gives me the correct intellisense, etc. Once I try to build it's like there is no longer a reference to the Thrift.dll. Any ideas?

I also submitted this to the Thrift Users Mailing List, I just thought maybe this was more general and someone here may be able to help.

Thanks,
-Sean

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Does VS2010 "Lose" my reference on build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010053/why-does-vs2010-lose-my-reference-on-build)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since you mentioned using VS 2010... I have seen this error/behavior sometimes when I am compiling a .NET 4.0 project and my target framework for the project is set to ".NET Framework 4.0 Client Profile" instead of ".NET Framework 4.0". So you might want to check that and see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks! That did it. That was strange that it worked being set to Client Profile for the older version of the Thrift.dll but not the newer one. I will have to read up on what the differences are.

Comment: Looks like it was because of the additional dependency on System.Web that was just added (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981204/net-framework-4-client-profile-system-web-dll).

Comment: Thank you so much for this. It's been driving me insane!

Comment: Thanks man!! It was driving me crazy!! Btw, if anyone wants to know why this "feature" actually exists, is if you want to build an application that only uses the standard .Net libraries. But since it is absolutely zero problem to install the full .Net framework, I see no use for this. Especially since it is the default option!

Comment: Just in case someone has been looking on how to change the Client Profile, I when to Project properties -> Compile -> Advanced compile options -> .Net Framework version

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem I had to switch from '.NET Framework 4.0 Client Profile' to '.NET Framework 4.0' and it worked because a referenced dll is compiled using the '.NET Framework 4.0'

Comment: This helped me out as a dll referenced in my project was using .NET Framework 4.5.1 and my project was 4.5... when I upgraded it to 4.5.1, the assembly reference was found and my project build was successful

Answer (score 0):

One Suggestion I have is to check for a file with 'refresh' in the extension E.g. Thrift.dll.refresh or something similar. This file is usually added on adding a refernce. Try removing this file, replace the dll and try builtign and running again.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I don't see any refresh files. I just started a complete new project with one line of code and added a reference to the new Thrift.dll and had the same problem :-/